# FB like button comment pop-up off screen

Tags: facebook-like

My like button has fixed positioned near the edge of the screen. As a result, clicking "Like", the comment pop-up box is half-on-screen, half-off, making posting comments difficult.

Any ideas? See the problem on the following screenshot:

[image]

Interestingly, the Google Plus button does not have this problem.

Comment: Anyone help with this? - surely someone else has had this problem!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an ancient post but for anyone else stumbling into it from google:
the solution is to simply add a css class for `.fb_iframe_widget` and give it a negative top margin with `!important`.

For example:

```
.fb_iframe_widget{
    margin-top:-163px !important;
}
```